# Billing web application aimed at designers?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a web application for managing billing/quotes/clients/etc. that is specifically aimed at print and web designers.

Must support UK and US companies.

Comment: See here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/whats-the-best-invoicing-webapp

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

- [Pipeline](http://www.pipelineworks.com) is a simple project billing app. that was designed by a company out of the UK. I haven't tried it but believe it will bill in US dollars as well.
- [FreeAgent](https://www.freeagent.com/) supports UK and US companies with support for billing, quotes, time tracking and project estimates (see the [tour page](https://www.freeagent.com/tour/)).